# Handler for incoming network packages

Tags: c++, template

I want to let you look through my `NetHandler` which is basically the component which gets notified when a full packet arrived (not like tcp-packet but my own type of packets) and handles it.

First of all, the `handle` method which gets called from the networking

```
void NetHandler::handle(int id, char* data, int len) {
#define P(ID, TYPE) case ID: try_handle<TYPE>(data, len); break
    switch (id) {
        P(0, game::networking::packets::Hello);
        P(1, game::networking::packets::Disconnect);
        P(2, game::networking::packets::Chat);
    default:
        unhandled(id);
    }
#undef P
}
```

Yeah... As you can see, a little `define` to create a `case` for me. `unhandled` just prints out an error.

Next, the try_handle<>()

```
template<typename T>
void try_handle(char* data, int len) {
    T packet;
    if (!packet.ParseFromArray(data, len)) {
        bad_packet(packet.GetTypeName(), len);
        return;
    }
    handle(packet);
}
```

It creates the actual corresponding `Packet` and parses it (I use google protobuf). `bad_packet`, again, just prints an error. Now the `handle`

```
#define STUB(TYPE) virtual void handle(TYPE& type) { unhandled(TYPE::default_instance().GetTypeName()); }
    STUB(game::networking::packets::Hello)
    STUB(game::networking::packets::Disconnect)
    STUB(game::networking::packets::Chat)
#undef STUB
```

I create a virtual method for every packet-type which calls `unhandled`. In my application I can now subclass this `NetHandler` and override the handler-methods for all packets I expect.

Now the other direction, **send** packets. I actually wanted a single send-method which takes every possible packet and just sends it. But it needs to send the id along with it, so I created a `PacketRegistry`

```
class PacketRegistry {
public:
    PacketRegistry() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            messages[i] = nullptr;
        reg<game::networking::packets::Hello>(0);
        reg<game::networking::packets::Disconnect>(1);
        reg<game::networking::packets::Chat>(2);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void reg(int id) {
        messages[id] = T::default_instance().GetDescriptor();
    }

    int getId(const google::protobuf::Message& message) {
        const google::protobuf::Descriptor* ptr = message.GetDescriptor();
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (messages[i] == ptr)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    const google::protobuf::Descriptor* messages[256];
};
```

As you can see, this is the **third** time I need to add every packet manually.

I tried to come up with some template-magic, but I'm not that experienced yet.
Something like

```
//in NetHandler
template<typename T>
void handle(T& packet) { unhandled(T::default_instance().GetTypeName()); }

//In a subclass
template<>
void handle<game::networking::packets::Chat>(game::networking::packets::Chat& chat) {   }
```

unfortunately doesn't work because... well... templates and virtual don't really like each other.

Any ideas how I can let the template-magic do more of the dirty work instead of defining methods, cases, and so on for every existing packet?

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

- Add/use inheritance for packet type (assuming you have something like game::networking::packets::PacketTypeBase that all packet types inherit from. Have GetDescriptor()/GetTypeName()/handle() on this base class
- Create a factory to go from `int id` to packet Type. Something like: `game::networking::packets::PacketTypeBase make_packet(int id);`
- Add a virtual function `handleInput(char* data, int len)` so your `NetHandler::handle` simply becomes `return make_packet(id).handleInput(data,len)`. The `default` can be handled by base class or separate UnknownPacket child class.

I would recommend using inheritance on packet type, not `NetHandler`. If you need flexibility, you can even pass a functor into the ctor of `NetHandler` if you want different work done on the PacketType by each instance of `NetHandler`

In general try to replace switch statement with inheritance and virtual functions. Factory/maker function comes in handy even during testing. Common functionality can be put in base class so you can avoid duplicate code (not need macros) & still do packet specific work.

Instead of having a hard-coded list of 256 (avoid magic numbers), use a `std::map` / `std::unordered_map`/HashMap so `find` / lookup will be faster in `getId` (use a data structure that  optimizes your most common case)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. Some notes though: 1.: I use google-protobuf, so all my messages are subclasses of protobuf's `Message`-class. I don't think I can add my own methods in there. 2. and 3.: So the package handles _itself_? Well, would probably be nice _iff_ I could add custom methods to the packets but I don't want to mess with the packets sourcecode after compiling it from .proto files.

Comment: You could add your own light wt wrapper around google-protobuf for what you need. Having your own class will also give you better control over your code in terms of future enhancements & maintenance (like you could choose a different serialization library for networking in the future and not have to change every interface)